# three.js doesn't show .obj in browser

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3dsmax, .obj

I am using this tutorial to load .obj and .material files in webgl using three.js - https://manu.ninja/webgl-3d-model-viewer-using-three-js

i just changed the assets but it doesn't show the new assets in chrome.

I also run local server to load assets from directory and also did --allow-file-access-from-files but still it doesn't show new obj and material files

Here's my code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<title>WebGL 3D Model Viewer Using three.js</title>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script src="three.js"></script>
<script src="Detector.js"></script>
<script src="OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="OBJLoader.js"></script>
<script src="MTLLoader.js"></script>
```

```
<script>

    if (!Detector.webgl) {
        Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
    }

    var container;

    var camera, controls, scene, renderer;
    var lighting, ambient, keyLight, fillLight, backLight;

    var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    init();
    animate();

    function init() {

        container = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.appendChild(container);

        /* Camera */

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
        camera.position.z = 3;

        /* Scene */

        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        lighting = false;

        ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
        scene.add(ambient);

        keyLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color('hsl(30, 100%, 75%)'), 1.0);
        keyLight.position.set(-100, 0, 100);

        fillLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color('hsl(240, 100%, 75%)'), 0.75);
        fillLight.position.set(100, 0, 100);

        backLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
        backLight.position.set(100, 0, -100).normalize();

        /* Model */

        var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
        mtlLoader.setBaseUrl('assets/');
        mtlLoader.setPath('assets/');
        mtlLoader.load('SYDNEY.mtl', function (materials) {

            materials.preload();

            materials.materials.default.map.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
            materials.materials.default.map.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

            var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
            objLoader.setPath('assets/');
            objLoader.load('SYDNEY.obj', function (object) {

                scene.add(object);

            });

        });

        /* Renderer */

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color("hsl(0, 0%, 10%)"));

        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        /* Controls */

        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        controls.enableDamping = true;
        controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
        controls.enableZoom = false;

        /* Events */

        window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyboardEvent, false);

    }

    function onWindowResize() {

        windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    }

    function onKeyboardEvent(e) {

        if (e.code === 'KeyL') {

            lighting = !lighting;

            if (lighting) {

                ambient.intensity = 0.25;
                scene.add(keyLight);
                scene.add(fillLight);
                scene.add(backLight);

            } else {

                ambient.intensity = 1.0;
                scene.remove(keyLight);
                scene.remove(fillLight);
                scene.remove(backLight);

            }

        }

    }

    function animate() {

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        controls.update();

        render();

    }

    function render() {

        renderer.render(scene, camera);

    }

</script>
```

Am i missing here something?

Comment: Could you also provide the obj/mtl files so that we can test the code? Does your browser actually access the obj/mtl files? Does the javascript code throw some errors or warnings to the console?

Comment: Hi, i got it render on browser with another three.js examples..